# from where do internet service providers get internet?

Tags: networking

I don't know how do the internet service providers (ISP) get the internet ?
for example I'm having a broadband connection from an xyz ISP. I think xyz gives me internet for some fee. But I'm not sure how do xyz connect to internet ? I mean to say they must be getting internet form somewhere then only they give internet to others or to me ?
  Thankyou in advance.

Comment: [The internet](http://www.blogcdn.com/www.engadget.com/media/2008/04/screen-grabs-linksys-internet.jpg) obviously...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not related to programming

Answer (score 3):

I had the same questions at the first time I know internet, I thought that it is similar with electricity that has some engines that will generate them.
The answer of your questions are actually off the topic of this forums but I will give you a hint.
Please do a research on google using keywords "How internet works".
This page may as well be a good starting points for you :
[How Stuff Works - Internet Technology](http://computer.howstuffworks.com/internet-technology-channel.htm)